# flash external interface in development mode

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a flash application that uses external interface (AS 3) to communicate via JS with webpage. All is working fine.

My development is in Flash Pro CS6 and its AS editor.
Wondering whether there is a way to simulate passing info back/forth while in the development interface? I've put in extra buttons to click, etc. to see whether code is working. However such always depends on just simulating external interface and adding things that will later have to be removed. Always then have to test newly compiled swf on the html page and go back and forth to get things right.

Since the flash development interface is self-contained, I doubt there is is a way to do this; but, thought worth asking the question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way in Flash Pro CS6.
It's probably possible in any other Flash development environment... in Flash Builder (or FDT), for instance, you can easily customize the URL or path to launch when debugging (like `http://localhost/test.html`, etc...).

Comment: That's what I thought. Wasn't aware might be possible in other development tools. I might check that out, as Flash Pro seems to be buggy, too, in things like code-hinting, completing imports, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this before:

```
if (Capabilities.playerType == 'External' || Capabilities.playerType == "StandAlone")
{
    // run some code that should happen during the development environment
    // it will also run if you double click a .swf or .exe projector file
    // ie. Jump straight to what happens when ExternalInterface call is successful
}
else
{
    // run code for when the .swf is embedded in a webpage
    // ie. Actually use ExternalInterface
}
```

It doesn't perfectly solve the problem, but I've found it helpful when you need to "get past" a part of the application. You could use it to skip and simulate ExternalInterface calls and just return some sample data that you can continue working with. It's easier than rebuilding back and forth for distribution/development.

Have a look at [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#playerType) for more info:

Hopefully it helps.